# Advertisement of Careers looks broken on Stack Exchange blog

Tags: bug, status-completed, jobs, design, blog

The advertisement of Careers has a small issue displaying jobs on the [Stack Exchange blog](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/). See screenshot below.

I'm using the latest Chrome Version 40.0.2214.91 m

[image: screen shot]

---

Exhibit B, with bonus all-caps title (Chrome 39):

[image: YOUR AD COULD BE HERE]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This was due to the SO redesign. When the style for the tags was updated on the job listings to reflect the new look, I missed a `float: none` in the stylesheet.